# CSS display one li at a time

Tags: css, angular

I am using Angular2. I have a list

```
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let show of (ann)">
            {{show}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to display one li at a time in every 3 second. Moreover, it will be infinite loop.

Here is my array:

```
ann: Array<any> = [
    {
      name: "ABC"
    },
    {
      name: "DEF"
    },
    {
      name: "ZZZ"
    }
];
```

- First 3 second: display ABC
- next 3 second: display DEF and ABC will be disappeared
- next 3 second: display ZZZ and DEF will be disappeared
- next 3 second: display ABC since it is end of the array. It will be
  infinite loop.

How can I do with CSS?

Comment: With CSS? Not possible!

Comment: Pls advice what should be the good way to implement it?

Comment: Use JS or JS/jQuery. Maybe AngularJS, but I don't have experience with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could achieve with animations in angular 2

Check preview https://plnkr.co/edit/fNZLspjrendI5SdK5gBC?p=preview

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  animations: [
    trigger('displayName', [
      state('in', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)' })),
      state('out', style({ opacity: 0, display: "none", transform: 'translateY(100%)' })),
      transition('in => out', [
        style({ transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1 }),
        animate('0.3s', style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)', opacity: 0 }))
      ]),
      transition('out => in', [
        style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)', opacity: 0 }),
        animate('0.3s 200ms', style({ transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1 }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  currentIndex: number;

  students: [] = [
    {
      name: "Alan",
      animationState: 'in'
    },
    {
      name: "Jake",
      animationState: 'out'
    },
    {
      name: "Harry",
      animationState: 'out'
    },
    {
      name: "Susan",
      animationState: 'out'
    },
    {
      name: "Sarah",
      animationState: 'out'
    },
    {
      name: "Esther",
      animationState: 'out'
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.currentIndex = 0;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval((function(){
      console.log(this.currentIndex);
      this.students[this.currentIndex].animationState = 'out';
      this.currentIndex++;
      if(this.currentIndex >= this.students.length) {
        this.currentIndex = 0;
      }
      this.students[this.currentIndex].animationState = 'in';
    }).bind(this), 3000);
  }
}
```

html

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let student of students" [@displayName]="student.animationState">
    {{student.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rxjs to acheive this 
in template

```
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
<div *ngFor="let student of $students | async">
    {{student.name}}
</div>
```

and in component

```
 students: Array<any> = [
    {
      name: "Alan"
    },
    {
      name: "Jake"
    },
    {
      name: "Harry"
    },
    {
      name: "Susan"
    },
    {
      name: "Sarah"
    },
    {
      name: "Esther"
    }
];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    var timer = 0;
    this.$students = Observable.from([[], ...this.students])
    .mergeMap(x => Observable.timer(timer++ * 1000).map(y => x))
    .scan((acc, curr, seed) => {
      acc.push(curr);
      return acc;
    });
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/MgJkFskZRp39FubSUbmH?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your answer. For your case, I want to display one name at a time e.g.  Alan (it will be disappeared when display Jake) same thing for the rest of the item. Alan will be displayed again after displayed Esther. So it is infinite loop.

Comment: Here you go, the revised [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/3jTHad5csAE4z9OwwtRA?p=preview) using RxJS. But I have no idea how to make the fade-in-out effect.

Comment: now with fade-in-out, still using RxJS. https://plnkr.co/edit/3jTHad5csAE4z9OwwtRA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you better, you're looking for something more like this:

```css
li {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: display 10s infinite;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

@keyframes display {
  0% {  opacity: 1  }
  20% { opacity: 0  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="num-1">
  <li>Jake</li>
  <li>Esther</li>
  <li>John</li>
  <li>Ann</li>
  <li>Someone</li>
</ul>
```

Or this:

```css
li {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: display 10s infinite;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

@keyframes display {
  20% {  opacity: 1  }
  30% { opacity: 0  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="num-1">
  <li>Jake</li>
  <li>Esther</li>
  <li>John</li>
  <li>Ann</li>
  <li>Someone</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Dont post 2 solution rather then merge or edit your old answer.